# Angular directive automatically move attributes to inner template element with replace

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When creating an angular directive with `replace: true` then the HTML in the DOM is going to be replaced with your template HTML. The attributes will then be put on the element that is going to replace your element.

e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="myName" my-directive>
```

will become something similar to

```
<div name="myName" my-directive>
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

when my template of the myDirective directive looks like

```
<div>
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

Now the question is how can I achieve that the `name` attribute is not set on the div but on the inner input element?

I could do it manually by be removing the attributes from the parent div element and add them to the input element. But I asked my-self whether there would be an automated way to do this with an option for angular directives.

Comment: can you provide sample plunker with your directive?

Comment: Not really, it isn't supported, you have to iterate over the attributes.